# Android: SQLite Constraint failed issue

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app, I am using SQLite database. While inserting data in one of my tables, I am facing weird issue of "SQLite exception: error 19". For the first time data gets inserted but, when I try to insert data again, it throws exception.

My **create table** query:

```
"CREATE TABLE Tickets ("
            + "ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
            + " UID varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not available'," + " OrderID int NOT NULL,"
            + " CarrierTicketNum varchar(15) NOT NULL,"
            + " TicketTypeID int NOT NULL," + " TankTypeID int NULL,"
            + " ProductObsGravity numeric NULL DEFAULT 0,"
            + " ProductHighTemp numeric NULL DEFAULT 0,"
            + " ProductLowTemp numeric NULL DEFAULT 0,"
            + " ProductObsTemp numeric NULL DEFAULT 0,"
            + " ProductBSW numeric NULL DEFAULT 0");
```

**Insert Query:**

```
public void insertTank(int OrderID, int TicketTypeID,
        String CarrierTicketNum, String TankNum, int TankTypeID,
        Double ProductObsTemp, Double ProductObsGravity, Double ProductBSW,
        Double GrossBarrels, Double NetBarrels) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("OrderID", OrderID);
    values.put("CarrierTicketNum", CarrierTicketNum);
    values.put("TankNum", TankNum);
    values.put("TicketTypeID", TicketTypeID);
    values.put("TankTypeID", TankTypeID);
    values.put("ProductObsTemp", ProductObsTemp);
    values.put("ProductObsGravity", ProductObsGravity);
    values.put("ProductBSW", ProductBSW);
    values.put("GrossBarrels", GrossBarrels);
    values.put("NetBarrels", NetBarrels);
    //try {
        db.insertOrThrow("Tickets", null, values);
    /*} catch (SQLiteException sqle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SQLITException: " + sqle.getMessage());
    }*/
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Following is the log detail:

```
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1617)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at com.dzo.dispatchcrude.driverapp.datalayer.DatabaseHandler.insertTank(DatabaseHandler.java:736)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at com.dzo.dispatchcrude.driverapp.NetBarrelActivity$1.onClick(NetBarrelActivity.java:103)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14110)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-08 13:54:57.610: E/AndroidRuntime(5713):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Read almost number posts but didn't got much help.

Comment: so u want to update data already exist?

Comment: No, I want to insert new data every time. Is there anything wrong in syntax?

Comment: So you simply need to insert a new row?

Comment: Yes, I want to insert new row

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the insert statement.  Inspect `values`.  Does it contain any nulls?

Comment: @Simon I checked all the values, they are not null. Is there any way to know on which constraint it fails?

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is that orderId is not unique.

Comment: @Simon Yes, it is not. For same order id, there can be multiple tickets. So, is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: What if I just want to get the result code from the insert? I've been searching everywhere and I can't get an answer. I want to make an insert and then check the result code. In this case it would be 19 (or SQLITE_CONSTRAINT). How can I get this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 ways to resolve your issue.

First:

Declare `PRIMARY KEY` as `autoincrement`

Second:

When trying to insert a new row, `provide different/unique ID` for the new row.

To test it, please `DELETE DATABASE` before running again your app.

**SOLUTION:**
This line should be:

```
+ "ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
```

instead of

```
+ "ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
```

Comment: In sqlite, AutoIncrement for primary key is not required, right? Although, I tried with it but didn't worked.

Comment: Do you need to put `NULL`? Maybe, that could be the problem.

Comment: If you put `NOT NULL` you can't put not null values, but if you put nothing you can put even null values or not null values.

Comment: But your error is not this. You error is probably that you're trying to insert two times value in the same row (so same ID). Try do delete your database and re-run app with `autoincrement` for ID. It should work

Comment: I tried, as you said. I deleted the database, and rerun my app with autoincrement. And the app crashed on second insert.

Comment: This line should be: `+ "ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"` pay attention you're not inserting null values where you can't. Can you have direct access to db? Just to read ID and some other data stored first time. I recommend using app `root browser`

Comment: Hi Stefano, it started working, only after I removed `NOT NULL` from primary key and where ever declared. But, its quiet strange. I have around 12 table in my database having same definition but none has caused trouble except this one.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from past eight hours I was messing with it.

Comment: @StefanoMunarini : how can i keep a field of my choice as PRIMARY key 
for example i have to keep name of the person as primary key (just an example)

Answer (score 1):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

You are getting constraint failed because you violated the constraint put on the field, like  passing a null value into a column that you declare as not null when you create your table.

I think `"ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"` this is causing you the problem, Please make sure it is `autoincrement` and the other values are not null as you put the Not null constraint.

Comment: But, I am not passing anything in Primary key. Also I tried with auto increment.

Comment: But one of the field UID(please refer create table query) will be updated from server while syncing, I cannot put anything to it. Can it be cause of problem?

Comment: Check the data you are inserting, and make sure two records do not have the same key.

Comment: I don't see any problem other than two records with same key here.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ID as int Value than

"ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"

instead of

"ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL"

if you are using ID as String Value than

use below line to insert value
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

(Where values is ovject of ContentValues object)

instead of

db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

keep coding....smile...